# FactoryGirl association with different name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have the following associations

```
class Training < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :attendees, through: :attendances
end

class Attendance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :training
  belongs_to :attendee, class_name: 'Employee'
```

The Attendance table has `attendee_id` and `training_id`.

Now, How can I create a valid `Attendance` with FactoryGirl?

Currently, I have the following code

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :attendance do
    training
    attendee
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :employee, aliases: [:attendee] do
    sequence(:full_name) { |n| "John Doe#{n}" }
    department
  end
end
```

But I get

```
  NoMethodError:
       undefined method `employee=' for #<Attendance:0x007f83b163b8e8>
```

I have also tried

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :attendance do
    training
    association :attendee, factory: :employee
  end
end
```

With the same outcome.

Thanks for your help (or being polite is not allowed on SO???).

Answer (score 8):

As you are probably aware FactoryGirl uses the symbol to infer what the class is, however when you are creating another factory with a different symbol for the same model you will need to tell FactoryGirl what the class to use is:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :attendance do
    training = { FactoryGirl.create(:training) }
    attendee = { FactoryGirl.create(:employee) }
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :employee, class: Attendee do
    sequence(:full_name) { |n| "John Doe#{n}" }
    department
  end
end
```

or can manually assign the relation (for example if you didn't want employee instance to be saved to database at this point):

```
FactoryGirl.build(:attendance, attendee: FactoryGirl.build(:employee))
```